# Using time capsule as a shared iTunes library

Tags: itunes, time-capsule

Is it possible to use a time capsule as a shared iTunes library?

To be clear, by shared library I mean a library that all the computers running iTunes in the network would recognise as a shared library and not merely a shared location to be configured in iTunes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, the Time Capsule doesn't have the software to run an iTunes library.

It can be used as external storage as you mentioned configuring it as a shared location. In this case iTunes would be running on another computer rather than on the Time Capsule.

Answer (score 1):

I have actually tried this and there are two ways the first is the shared location works well most of the time. However, lose a connection while you are connected and you will lose configuration with teh destination folder.

Best work arround is to have an external HDD or the TC with all your music connected to one computer and then make your library shared so that the other computer can access the music over the network.